# Помогите разобраться в алгоритме SwingingDoors

Tags: алгоритм

Я просто не понимаю как приспособить его под сухие числа. В графическом плане все понятно. Откладываем погрешность и строим лучи ло новой точки если точка не входит в коридор то вращаем луч до пересечения. Когда коридор открывается, то сохраняется новая точка, а точками межд уними можно пренебречь

У нас есть массив значений от датчика. Берем первое значение и откладываем погрешность, понятно. строим вторую точку и проводим от точек с погрешностями лучи. Вот с этим не понятно какие лучи я могу получить, и как смотреть входит новая точка в коридор или нет

Comment: Вот ссылка на алгоритм https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/105652/

Comment: Там же есть ссылка на код

Comment: я не силен в делфи

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, смущает фраза "вращаем луч", поскольку описание в статье дано достаточно полное для воспроизведения.

Есть базовая точка `Base = P[b]`. Есть две опорные - верхняя `U` и нижняя `L`, отстоящие по оси Y от базовой на величину погрешности.

По приходу следующей точки `Current= P[b+1]` рассчитываем наклоны лучей из U и L в точку `Current`  (коэффициент k в уравнении прямой `y=kx+b`)

```
USlope = (Current.Y - U.Y) / (Current.X - Base.X)
LSlope = (Current.Y - L.Y) / (Current.X - Base.X)
```

Эти лучи пересекаются, и `USlope < LSlope`

Переходим к следующей точке `Current= P[b+2]`, считаем для нее наклоны `NewUSlope` и `NewLSlope` относительно всё тех же опорных.

В зависимости от новых наклонов есть варианты, которые нужно обработать в одном if или switch:

1) Если `NewUSlope > NewLSlope`, то лучи больше не пересекаются, коридор раскрылся, и прошлую точку `P[b+1]` берем за базовую, пересчитывая наклоны USlope LSlope

2) `NewUSlope <= USlope и NewLSlope >= LSlope` - точка находится внутри коридора, сам коридор не изменяется

3) `NewUSlope > USlope` точка выше верхнего луча, обновляем наклон верхнего луча `USlope = NewUSlope` - коридор слегка подраскрылся, но не полностью

4) `NewLSlope < USlope` точка ниже нижнего луча, обновляем наклон нижнего лучао луча `LSlope = NewLSlope` - коридор слегка подраскрылся, но не полностью

Только в случае 1) точка `P[b+1]` считается важной и записывается